# Restrict Azure Active Directory access by cloning built-in roles and using Roles and administrators

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have created one `App Registration`, called `Report`, under AAD and its app under `Enterprise Application`.

I want to restrict the people access (full CRUD) to the Report app in both `App Registration` and `Enterprise Application`, and no access to other apps in AAD.

Below is my idea?

1 Clone `Cloud application administrator` to create a new role

2 Add people to the new role,

3 Add the new role to `Roles and administrators` of `Report` under both `App Registration` and `Enterprise Application`

Does it work? Does anyone have a better idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For user to be granted any permissions over only the selected app registration.

1. Create a new role using the following PowerShell script
2. Assign the role using the PowerShell script
3. Create a role with the Microsoft Graph API
   3.a. Create the role definition.
   3.b. Create the role assignment.
4. Assign a custom role scoped to a resource

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/custom-create

Additional Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/custom-create#create-a-new-custom-role-to-grant-access-to-manage-app-registrations

Assign Azure roles using Azure Resource Manager templates : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-template

Comment: Thanks. Is it correct that there is no clone function in Azure for cloning an existing built-in role?

Comment: Yes you are correct Pingpong, we can clone only from the custom Role and not from the built In roles.

Comment: thanks, I wonder if you know if my steps in the OP will work combining your links. So other people have access only to the assigned App Registrations and Enterprise Application, and no other apps?

Comment: Yes Pingpong it should work combining the steps and links provided. Only thing is we need to create a Custom role instead of cloning Built in Roles.